# Inject css into exsisting web page

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to modify the CSS of a website where I don't have access to change the css.

I am developing some custom templates for a company that is using the 3rd party software 'Inksoft', which allows the creation of stores and also includes a design studio for designing your own t-shirts, etc.

The templates they provide are not the greatest, so I want to modify the css to make them a little better. There are places I can insert html, so I can use JavaScript. Someone mentioned possibly using a setTimeout.

Here is an example of a page created using one of their templates:
http://stores.inksoft.com/Trevor_Friedrich/

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9):

http://jsfiddle.net/wkCnb/  you can definitely use JavaScript to add CSS to your page.

HTML

```
<div>test</div>
```

JavaScript on DOMReady

```
var cssText = "div { background-color: black; color: white;}";
var css = document.createElement("style");
css.type = "text/css";
if("textContent" in css)
    css.textContent = cssText;
else
    css.innerText = cssText;
document.body.appendChild(css);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can insert HTML, then you can create a `<style>` tag, and put the rules you want inside of that.  If they conflict with existing rules, you can apply `!important` to those.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm sorry I should have specified that the software only gives you access to insert HTML in certain parts of the page, such as their defined 'header' and 'footer'.

Comment: The style element is allowed to be placed outside of the head element in HTML5.  http://html5doctor.com/the-scoped-attribute/

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying now, thanks! Also, when I contacted the software company to inquire about this, the guy said 'about the only thing I have seen work for this is to adjust the setTimeout'. Do you know why he would suggest this?

Comment: That makes no sense in the context of CSS.  There is a `setTimeout` function in JavaScript, though.  Either way, the guy sounds confused.

Comment: You should strongly consider the possibility that the guy doesn't know what he's talking about.

Comment: Yeah, someone else was saying that didn't make much sense either. All I could think of was that there's some sort of code in there that runs dynamically and is changing the css constantly and the only way to override that is to use the setTimeout in Javascript?? Did you have a chance to look at the code on that page I linked to? The only way I have of inserting HTML/JavaScript is via this user interface: http://www.moonandfox.com/Untitled-2.png

Comment: I did.  I suspect if you click the HTML button on that editor, you can inject a style tag into the content.  It's possible that they're filtering that out, but if they are, they'd probably be even more likely to be filtering script tags.  Have you tried it?

Comment: No I got on a tangent reading about JQuery. Going to try it now!

Comment: Ok so I tried adding a <style> section in the html editor: http://www.moonandfox.com/Untitled-2.png using this code: <style>
body {background-color:red;}
</style> However, once I click update and go back to the html editor, the style code is gone. Perhaps since the site is not in HTML5 it is ignoring style tags outside the scope of the <head>? I was able to add a script in however: http://www.moonandfox.com/Untitled-3.png So considering this, what do you guys think is the best means of overriding the current css? Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: @Rachael: If something is stripping out the style tags, but not javascript, you should be able to use an approach like the one recommended by LastCoder.  You may or may not have to use a document load or timeout.  I'd first try to inject the javascript directly in a script block and go from there.